# hector_slam simulation fuerte 10.04 vs 12.04

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,
I am trying to  setup hector_slam simulation on Lucid Lynx 10.04, ROS Fuerte using svn copy from http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/
I am also facing some gazebo problems. This may be because of upgradation to 1.x.x

In forum, I found many people are successfully using hector_slam.

Is it easier to setup hector_slam simuation and stack in Ubuntu 12.04 for ROS Fuerte ?
What are your working configurations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38895/hector_slam-simulation-fuerte-10.04-vs-12.04/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no major changes or differences between hector_slam for electric or fuerte and mapping should work for both (and 10.04 or 12.04 shouldn't matter otherwise). OTOH, the current fuerte gazebo version available from .debs appears to still be buggy. I noticed quite a few things that worked correctly in electric's gazebo and now are broken in fuerte (for example [broken URDF models](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/59)).

If you do not need anything that is available only in fuerte, I'd recommend sticking with electric for the moment (in case you want to use gazebo and experience issues).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0